# FAQ sidebar for per site metas

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, per-site-meta, sidebar, meta-faq

Meta Stack Exchange has a nice side bar over when you are on the [main page](//meta.stackexchange.com) (the one you hit when you go to the 'meta' link, not the 'questions' tab).

> [image: Frequently Asked Sidebar]

It's great.  You can see there is a 'faq' section, it's right there when you go to meta, and you can then go and dig into more faqs if you need to.

Per-site metas don't have this faq sidebar.  A new user going to meta would have to ***know that such a tag exists*** and dig into the tags tab:

> [image: tabs]

Then look around and see that faq isn't on the first page

> [image: tags]

and either type it in, or go to the second page to see it.

> [image: tags page 2]

## Many of you probably got bored looking at the pictures above.  So do most users who *should* be reading the FAQ.

Make it easier for these users to find the FAQ posts.  Put that 'Frequently Asked' sidebar on per-site metas too.

Comment: One could go to [Questions / frequent](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent), which is different from [tag:faq], but has an overlap with the latter. But yes, this is still too non-obvious clicks away from an inexperienced user.

Comment: @CareBear [votes](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) though again, that doesn't always match faq either.  Note that for some reason the +277, 6k view "Open Letter" doesn't show up doesn't show up in the frequent tab but does show up in the votes tab (that might be a bug?).  Very few of the P.SE FAQ questions have significant views (the FAQ Index for example only has 246 views... I didn't even know it was there... and given that its last activity was 2 years ago, I'm not sure many mods did either).

Comment: "Frequent" tab orders by the numbers of links (duplicate or otherwise linked), not by views or votes. Despite the popularity of your letter, only six questions are linked to it.

Comment: @CareBear ... so the controversial posts ones from the past and the 'which site do I post on' show up there, while the 'this is part of the FAQ that people should read and isn't controversial' get completely missed.

Comment: Well, FAQ means "frequently asked", not "important to read".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, this can be enabled on a per-side basis... The only downside I see is that *by default* the meta homepage sidebar features chat:

[image: 123 PEOPLE CHATTING]

The bulk of meta sites are relatively quiet, with chat being a somewhat more informal place to introduce yourself to the regulars. However, on sites where meta does actually attract a large volume of *frequently asked questions*, showing the FAQ probably trumps this need.

If you believe your site would benefit from this feature, I recommend proposing it on your site's meta (post a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) there) and letting the community decide which they'd rather promote: chat or FAQ. Note that it's also possible to rotate between the two (chat 50%, FAQ 50%; chat 30%, FAQ 70%; etc.)