# Is the FAQ accessible by a link on the sites (besides MSE)?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, meta-faq

Is there a direct link to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) anywhere consistent on all of the sites? Either the main MSE FAQ or the individual site FAQs (which generally link back to MSE's).

Places I have looked (using SO and SU to explore):

- The main page of the site. On MSE there is a link under "Frequently Asked" on the right. On the rest of the sites, the word "FAQ" does not appear on the main page.
- In the bottom navigation bar.
- In the top-bar help drop down.
- In the Help Center main page (via top bar or bottom footer). The word "FAQ" does not appear.
- On the Tour page.
- On the Ask Question page.
- On the old and new user profile pages.
- Searching the Help Center for "faq" ([8 results, none of them the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=faq), although while some results do have links to individual FAQ questions buried inside, they go to unexpected places, e.g. SU's https://superuser.com/help/deleted-questions links to SO's https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that which silently redirects to an MSE FAQ entry, bypassing SU's FAQ).

I am surprised that it is in none of those places, especially the main page and Help Center. Ways I *have* found to get to the FAQ:

- From MSE, search for the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag, click any result, go to the FAQ index via the link (except for the occasional FAQ page that doesn't have a link to the FAQ index, <strike>such as [the very first result in the FAQ tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer)</strike> [Tag is now removed from that post as indirect result of this; [history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/245122/1).])
- From an individual site, same deal.

Isn't there a FAQ link somewhere? If not, can there be? Perhaps in the bottom bar of each site, or in the help center, or in the top-bar help dropdown (even better!).

There is a very closely related feature request at [FAQ sidebar for per site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240186/faq-sidebar-for-per-site-metas). This is for the "frequently asked" sidebar, the same as the one on MSE. [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/faq-sidebar-on-programmers-meta) made a specific request and got that sidebar. However, a link to Programmers' [FAQ index](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/faq-index-for-programmers-se) does not appear in that list, and most of the [results for the tag there](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) are not linked back to the index [at the moment](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/faq-index-links) (same as described above for MSE's tag, although Programmers' only has 18 entries and the tag results list is easy to browse through, this is still significant as it also means a link to the larger main network FAQ is missing). This post is about a direct link to the index as a common site feature (linking to the main MSE FAQ if there's no per-site FAQ), rather than the rare per-site sidebar with a subset of FAQ entries and no guaranteed link back.

It seems like, since so much effort is put into the FAQ, we'd want people to be able to readily find it. Especially because it contains a lot of information that complements what is in the Help Center (we often direct users to the Help Center, which has a lot of great basic info, but is incomplete on its own).

Comment: Wow, that FAQ is awesome! I thought I'd been through every possible help page, but I've never seen this. I agree 100% that it should be as easy to find as possible! SE is great, but hard to "do" properly, and anything that can make it easier should be supported.

Comment: @Sklivvz Heh, so, after a year and a half of sleepless nights, staring at my bad capitalization, you finally snapped?