# How about having "Frequently Asked" at right panel on child metas also?

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta

On the [home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com) of Meta Stack Exchange, the list of FAQ are displayed at the right panel:

> [image]

How about applying the similar feature on child metas who are having [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)? I mean listing those questions tagged as [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) at the right panel of child meta.

This sounds very useful especially for new users who might be visiting Meta first time!

Comment: Btw, it looks that *featured* are also included in the list!

Comment: What kinds of questions would need to show up for child metas? Would it be site-specific stuff like homework policies? Or maybe something about the general scope of the site? I can't see why a new user'd care about those being there.

Comment: @Chair those are tagged with FAQ. e.g [these](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) on Hinduism Meta.

Comment: This is already active on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Glorfindel that may be because MSO is ancienter than MSE!

Comment: I think the most important thing to be users who're new to meta is how _meta_ works, not about the main site; most FAQs are about the main site. It may be useful to point them to a nice detailed description of what meta is and how it works. To find the important stuff on meta, it's easy to head to the highest-voted posts. On metas, unlike main sites, the highest voted posts are usually the most important stuff. The new users who visit meta are probably the ones who're more interested in site policies and are likely to plan to hunt down an FAQ tag or something once they know where they are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FAQ sidebar for per site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240186/faq-sidebar-for-per-site-metas)

Comment: This is not so much a duplicate as suggested by bobble's close reason, the answer there says that this question should be closed as: "Relates to only one specific network site"; since this should be asked on the particular site's per-site-meta. --- It wouldn't be a "duplicate" of a question asked **4** years previously in any event, as after that period of time it's reasonable to reask.

Comment: I agree with Rob's comment about it not being a dupe, but it's neither about a specific site, it's about the meta pages of all sites (except Meta). VTLO.